# How to solve for positive integral n for which the equation $\frac{x-8}{n-10}=\frac{n}{x}$ has no real solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve for positive integral $n$ for which the equation
$$\frac{x-8}{n-10}=\frac{n}{x}$$ has no real solutions?

Comment: Hint: It's not allowed to divide by zero.

Comment: I don't see any integral. Did you mean $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{10\}$

Comment: maybe an author have to write integer instead integral....

Comment: You can see an example in any decent textbook. (: You know, some children don't have access to MSE. Don't take this site for granted and show some effort.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak, I clearly doubt nobody would notice such a typo.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Calling it integral number is fine too; it's common in number theory.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Calling it integral number is fine too; it's common in number theory.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $n\ne 10$. Now we have
$$x(x-8)=n(n-10)$$
or $$x^2-8x-n(n-10)=0$$
we wish this equation to have no real solution, therefore the indiscriminate must be negative:
$$64+4n(n-10)<0\implies\\
4 (n^2-10n+16)<0\implies\\
4(n-2)(n-8)<0$$
can you proceed now?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x-8}{n-10}=\frac nx\iff x^2-8x-(n^2-10n)=0$$

The above quadratic has no real solution iff

$$\Delta=8^2+4(n^2-10n)<0\iff (n-2)(n-8)<0\iff 2<n<8$$

and, of course, you can't divide by zero, so also $\;n\;$ cannot be...